# Having trouble exporting to text file

Tags: ms-access, vba, export, ms-access-2000

I am having some trouble exporting out to a file from VBA. Some things to be aware of are that `JobDetail` is a valid export SpecName and `2_JobDetail` is a query that combines some info with stuff from other fields and tables. When I try to run I get the error  like below on my `DoCmd.TransferText` method call. Advice? am I doing something wrong? code below.

[image]

```
Public Function exportJobDetailRecs(dateStr As String)
    'Docmd.TransferText(acexport,specName,TableName, FileName,HasfieldNames,HTMLTableName)   
    DoCmd.TransferText acExport, _
                        "JobDetail", _
                        "2_JobDetail", _
                        "P:\Folder1\Folder2\Tracker\" + CStr(dateStr + "_OrderStatus_jobdets.txt")   
    exportJobDetailRecs = CStr(dateStr + "_OrderStatus_jobdets.txt")
End Function
```

Some questions people have asked:

1. Yes  - Do you have full permission to write to the file (i.e. full permission to the folder as well as the text file if you are not creating it with code)
2. Yes  - Check path (folder name with space/etc) for mistakes.

   - and I'm copying with Shift-Right click, then copy as Path, and adding a trailing `\` manually
3. Yes  - Have you try exporting manually and overwriting your existing spec and see if that works? If so, try runs the code again afterward
4. Yes  - Have you confirmed JobDetail is an export spec instead of an import spec?

   - and manual exports work fine
5. 3-50 - How many records does 2_JobDetail currently return?
6. Same - Try the export (temporarily) to "P:\Folder1\Folder2\Tracker\a.txt"

   - It doesn't care what folder (that exists) I point it to, it wont go
7. None - Also make sure that there are no punctuation marks in strDate

   - http://pastie.org/private/0kdf2wvkg1wug5physna for the function I use to make dateStr

Comment: Hi PsychoData,
Start with something simple:  
1) Do you have full permission to write to the file (i.e. full permission to the folder as well as the text file if you are not creating it with code)  2)Check path (folder name with space/etc)

Comment: Ok, have you try exporting manually and overwriting your existing spec and see if that works?  If so, try runs the code again afterward

Comment: Same results as listed

Comment: Yes, and it works fine when I export manually.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a new table and export it to your c:\.  That should work and you could further testing bit by bit (changing your destination folder, then file name, etc).  If exporting to C:\ won't work there might be different access right level between your user and the MS access you are using

Comment: Not working. I can make directories and files with other parts of the code. Specifically later on I read two files in and write out a third combination file, no problems. It's only the export line that has problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It wanted me to create the destination files too, not just the directories before I could copy to it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Solution: I changed all the column names and it worked. Something about the column names MS Access didn't like. I named them f1, f2, f3...

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem; I changed the encoding from 'Westeuropean (Windows)' to 'Unicode (UTF-8)' and that did the trick. The problem probably had to do with this invisible 'character' in one of the fieldnames: "ï»¿observer".